# How to make a batch file go to a random ":"?

Tags: batch-file

So I like when the batch file go to a random ":" like `:page1 / :page2 / :page3` every time. But you might be confused reading this so can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set /a page=(%random% %% 3) + 1
goto page%page%
```